# metabox wordpress show in frontend

Tags: metabox, iframe

Hello I have a metabox field called name this returns an iframe that I have placed but it returns all the code of the iframe and it was not executed.
What is missing in my code to show it in the frontend?

```
$maintitlet =  get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name', true );
echo $maintitle;
```

show the code. I have put that space because it did not allow me to publish the code iframe

```
<iframe src="link.html" width="670" height="500"></iframe>
```

Comment: Your variable names don't match: `$maintitlet` and `$maintitle` are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

The output is escaped, so it will not display html, try this :

just save the value of the src attribute

```
<iframe src="<?php echo esc_attr__( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name', true ) ); ?>" width="670" height="500">
```